# Perl pack/unpack/shift

Tags: perl, bit, shift, unpack, pack

I've been having this problem in Perl for a few days now, and after scouring countless man pages, perldocs and googling too many search terms, hopefully someone here can help me out.

I am given two strings which represent hex values, i.e. "FFFF", not the Perl hex number 0xFFFF.  Given two of these strings, I wish to convert them to binary form, perform a bitwise AND of the two, then take the output of this and examine each bit from LSB to MSB.

I have two problems right now; converting the hex string into a hex number, and shifting 
the result of the bitwise AND.

For converting the hex string into a hex number, I've tried the following approaches which don't seem to work when I print them out to examine:

```
$a = unpack("H*", pack("N*", $a));

$a = sprintf("%H", $a);
```

Using a 'print' to examine each of these does not show a correct value, nor does using 'sprintf' either...

The second problem I have occurs after I perform a bitwise AND, and I want to examine each bit by shifting right by 1.  To avoid the previous problem, I used actual Perl hex numbers instead of hex strings (0xffff instead of "ffff").  If I try to perform a shift right as follows:

```
#Convert from hex number to binary number

$a = sprintf("%B", $a);
$b = sprintf("%B", $b);

$temp = pack("B*", $a) & pack("B*", $b);
$output = unpack("B*", $temp);
```

At this point everything looks fine, and using a 'print' I can see that the values of the AND operation look right, but when I try to shift as follows:

```
$output = pack("B*", $output);
$output = $output >> 1;
$output = unpack("B*", $output);
```

The resulting value I get is in binary form but not correct.

What is the correct way of performing this kind of operation?

Answer (score 9):

There's no such thing as a "hex number". A number is a number, a hexadecimal representation of a number is just that - a *representation*.

Just [turn it into a number](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) and use bitwise and.

```
my $num = (hex $a) & (hex $b);
print ($num & 1, "\n") while ($num >>= 1)
```

Comment: Did you mean `while ($num >>= 1)` ?